# Como fazer uma função aceitar um parametro slice de qualquer tipo?

Tags: golang

Criei essa função shuffle, porém gostaria que ela aceitasse e retornasse qualquer tipo de de slice

```golang
func Shuffle(ptr *[]int, seed int64) []int {

    rand.Seed(seed)
    rand.Shuffle(len(*ptr), func(i, j int) { (*ptr)[i], (*ptr)[j] = (*ptr)[j], (*ptr)[i] })


    return *ptr
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como, você tem que especificar o tipo de entrada e saída.

---

Tem duas soluções:

1. Crie uma função para cada tipo, que é o preferível.
2. Utilize `interface{}`.

---

Se quiser ir para o segundo caso, pode fazer algo como:

```
func Shuffle(ptr []interface{}, seed int64) []interface{} {
   rand.Seed(seed)

   switch ptr := ptr.(type) {
   case *[]int:
       rand.Shuffle(len(*ptr), func(i, j int) { (*ptr)[i], (*ptr)[j] = (*ptr)[j], (*ptr)[i] })
   case *[]int64:
       rand.Shuffle(len(*ptr), func(i, j int) { (*ptr)[i], (*ptr)[j] = (*ptr)[j], (*ptr)[i] })
   case *[]int32:
       rand.Shuffle(len(*ptr), func(i, j int) { (*ptr)[i], (*ptr)[j] = (*ptr)[j], (*ptr)[i] })
//...

}

    return ptr
}
```

Note, que o resultado já é um `interface{}`, então você terá que usar um [type assertation](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15):

```
valor, ok := Shuffle(....).(*[]int)
```

Comment: PS: Os slices já são "ponteiros por padrão", eles são passados como referencia e não são copiados, então não me parece ter um motivo para retorna-los como resultado da função (e nem de usar `*[]int` como entrada. Mas, isto é outro tópico.

Comment: Talvez possa também usar o ` reflect.SliceHeader` com o `unsafe`, mas não sei se vale a pena.

Comment: Existe diferença em performance se usar ponteiros? Pois para mim é mais fácil a leitura e entendimento de ```Shuffle(&slice, seed)``` do que ```Shuffle(slice, seed)```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar algumas funções do `package` [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect) pra tornar esse código genérico, a principal é esta.

> ```golang
> func Swapper(slice interface{}) func(i, j int)
> ```
>
> Swapper returns a function that swaps the elements in the provided
> slice.
>
> Swapper panics if the provided interface is not a slice.

Ela retorna outra função que é um *trocador* para o *slice*, que faz a mesma coisa que esta linha no seu código:

```golang
(*ptr)[i], (*ptr)[j] = (*ptr)[j], (*ptr)[i]
```

Exemplo usando esses recursos:

```golang
type AnySlice interface{}

func Shuffle(slice AnySlice, seed int64) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(slice)

    swapper := reflect.Swapper(rv.Interface())

    rand.Seed(seed)

    rand.Shuffle(rv.Len(), func(i, j int) {
        swapper(i, j)
    })
}
```

Exemplo de chamada:

```golang
intValues := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
strValues := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}

seed := time.Now().UnixNano()

Shuffle(intValues, seed)
Shuffle(strValues, seed)

fmt.Printf("%#v\n%#v", intValues, strValues)
```

Como *slices* já são "ponteiros", o uso de `&` e `*` é desnecessário nesse caso.